# Nodejs websocket server, http trigger

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a http/websocket nodejs server. I want to use the action of visiting a url to trigger a websocket send to a different socket client.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8081});
var http = require("http");
var sys = require("sys");

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){
  response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello");
  if (request.url == "/"){
    sys.puts("hit site")
    wss.on('connection', function(ws){
      sys.puts("sent msg");
      ws.send("photo plox");
    });
  }
  response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

My websocket client is not receiving the message as the browser hits the url. If I visit the site a number of times without the client connected and then and then connect the client, 1 message is sent for each visit all at once.

How can I go about using a browser url visit to trigger a websocket send?

Comment: check this  [link](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) it may be the issue regarding message type use sendUTF for utf8 type or sendBytes for binary type message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not managing the connections to the WebSocketServer properly. In your code you're only listening for connections AFTER you've received an HTTP request. Try something like this instead:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8081});
var http = require("http");
var sys = require("sys");

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){
  response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello");
  if (request.url == "/"){
    for (var i = 0; i < wss.client.length; i++) {
      var ws = wss.clients[i];
      sys.puts("sent msg");
      ws.send("photo plox");
    }
  }
  response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: I think you can use [`wss.clients`](https://github.com/einaros/ws#server-sending-broadcast-data) instead of having to keep track of the connections yourself.

Comment: @robertklep nice tip! I'm no ws expert, I just spotted the obvious problem

Comment: Edited per @robertklep's comment.

Comment: Not an expert myself, just saw the broadcast implementation ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great example with socket.io, you might have to change few things.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/real-time-web-analytics-with-node-js-and-socket-io/